# Monodevelop fails to startup on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I'm a Linux noop, and I was trying to get monodevelop up and running on my ubuntu 7.1 box. I added the Universal repository (or something, I don't really know) to my repository, and then issued apt-get install monodevelop. It was easy and quick. I now have mono and monodevelop installed on my machine. Now, each time I try to launch monodevelop I receive an exception of type

> System.TypeInitializationException

The exception message is

> An exception was thrown by the type
>   initializer for
>   MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.IdeApp --->
>   System.ApplicationException: Couldn't
>   create a remote process.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Monodevelop works great in Jaunty (and comes along without adding repositories).  Can you upgrade your Ubuntu install?

Comment: OK, I'm following the instruction here http://www.ubuntu.com/getubuntu/upgrading but seems like my system has a lot of broken packages. Will try to download the newest ubuntu.

Comment: Downloading the latest in your situation is probably the fastest solution anyways as long as you can spare the time to start fresh with the system.  Upgrading to 8.xx to turn around and upgrade to 9.10 isn't worth the trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Since the time of 7.10, both Ubuntu and Mono (with it's IDE) have come a long way. I'd also suggest an upgrade. (For me Monodevelop works great on Ubuntu 9.04, but I'll give 9.10 a try this weekend)